# direction on image pattern description and representation

Tags: image-processing, pattern-matching, image-segmentation

I have a basic question regarding pattern learning, or pattern representation. Assume I have a  complex pattern of this form, could you please provide me with some research directions or concepts that I can follow to learn how to represent (mathematically describe) these forms of patterns? in general the pattern does not have a closed contour nor it can be represented with analytical objects like boxes, circles etc.

[image: binary discrete pattern]

Answer (score 0):

By mathematically describe I'm assuming you mean derive from the image a vector of values that represents the content of the image.  In computer vision/image processing we call this an "image descriptor".

There are several image descriptors that could be applied to pixel based data of the form you showed, which appear to be 1 value per pixel i.e. greyscale images.

One approach is to perform "spatial gridding" where you divide the image up into a regular grid of a constant size e.g. a 4x4 grid.  You then average the pixel values within each cell of the grid.  Then concatenate these values to form a 16 element vector - this coarsely describes the pixel distribution of the image.

Another approach would be to use "image moments" which are 2D statistical moments.  Use this equation:
[image]

where f(x,y) is they pixel value at coordinates (x,y).  W and H are the image width and height.  The mu_x and mu_y indicate the average x and y.  The values i and j select the order of moment you want to compute.  Various orders of moment can be combined in different ways for example in the "Hu moments" we can compute 7 numbers using combinations of image moments:

[image]

The cool thing about the Hu moments is you can scale, rotate, flip etc the image and you still get the same 7 values which makes this a robust ("affine invariant") image descriptor.

Hope this helps as a general direction to read more in.

Comment: Thank you jcollomosse for your pointer, I will follow this track to see how it works out. it seems that Hu's moments are not invertible and can only be used for classification purposes. what I am looking for, is a method to represent patterns efficiently and accurately. Like PCA and KPCA but more optimized for discrete patterns that have "connectivity" or "continuity"

Comment: Ok. You might want to try something like a Fourier descriptor if you need a generative / invertible representation.  It might be worth editting your original question to make this clear, since most descriptors and thus others people may recommend are also not generative.